# multiplexer 8x1 in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i try to do in EDA playground platform a code for 8x1 multiplexer put something is going wrong. The show me an error that i search it and i found that is from verilog language and i don't understand why? i check again and again my code and i dont find any mistake. please see the code from the link below to run it and help me to solve is problem and i understand why is apear me that error

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2T3x

Comment: Please include the relevant code and the precise error message as text in this post.

Comment: and please add this code formatted with the code tags for improved readability

Answer (score 1):

you need to rename your testbench to something different to your module.

Call it '`multiplexer_test`' instead.

i.e. the following lines

**testbench.vhd**

```
ENTITY multiplexer IS
END multiplexer;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF multiplexer IS
```

to

```
ENTITY multiplexer_test IS
END multiplexer_test;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF multiplexer_test IS
```

And also you need to change the top entity to `multiplexer_test` instead of `testbench`

i.e.

[image: top module]

Or if you just rename the testbench module from `multiplexer` to `testbench` then you don't need to do the second step

Comment: let me know if there is any problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. My code is now working

```
-- Code your design here
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

--declaration for 8x1
entity mux8x1 is   
    port( I : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- input that need 8x1
           s: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); --is the enable
           Y: out std_logic -- output of 8x1 is the output
    );
end mux8x1;

architecture behavioral of mux8x1 is
    signal f0,f1,f2,f3 : std_logic;
begin
    process(I,S)
    begin
        if s(0)='0' then 
            f0<=I(7);
            f1<=I(5);
            f2<=I(3);
            f3<=I(1);
        else 
            f0<=I(6);
            f1<=I(4);
            f2<=I(2);
            f3<=I(0);
        end if;

        if (s(1)='0' and s(0)='0')then
            Y<=f0;
            if (s(1)='0' and s(0)='1')then
                Y<=f1;
                if (s(1)='1' and s(0)='0')then
                    Y<=f2;
                    if (s(1)='1' and s(0)='1')then
                        Y<=f3;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: That exact code appears in another question by another user, and is functionally wrong! See at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613522/multiplexer-in-eda-play-ground